# Load HTML from html file into Vue div

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

So, I'm using jsfiddle to follow [THIS](https://jsfiddle.net/arvidkahl/gxdn6ycv/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=gxdn6ycv)
    {{respondedText}}

```html
<div>{{respondedText}}</div>
```

However, say I want to read in HTML content from a file or site and then load it into that div; instead of displaying "Event Received: Event 2".

This is ultimately a building block for me in what I'm trying to use it for. I'm hoping, by successfully getting this example to work, that I can build a webapp that has buttons that, onpress, will load html from another local file on my server without reloading the entire page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To fill an element with active HTML you have to use the `v-html` directive

```
<div v-html="respondedTest"></div>
```

This will allow any valid HTML but you have to note that you can't load Vue components asynchronously this way; It's only for static HTML.

Here is your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gxdn6ycv/23/) Updated to send some HTML with the click events.

EDIT:

Looking into the spirit of your question you might want to look at [vue-router](http://router.vuejs.org) It's a pretty good system to allow you to have a single page app with a routing system similar to a standard page routing system. It also allows you to mount Vue components in your pages instead of static HTML.

Comment: I was able to use v-html successfully before to just insert something like '<p>test response</p>, but I'm wondering how to get html from a file. In the javascript section would I use something like respondedText = this.respondedText.load('www.google.com'); ?

Comment: I just saw your edit, would vue-router be a good option for loading in dynamic html content?

Comment: You would need to use ajax to load a resource. I'd suggest [Axios](https://alligator.io/vuejs/rest-api-axios/) for its easy integration with Vuejs. You'd perform the get/post request and pass the returned body text to the element.

Comment: Depends on how you're generating your dynamic content. Usually with dynamic content you want to build structural Vue files and fill them with data from an outside source. If you want to generate irregular structure you'd be best to use the `v-html` method

Comment: Yes, I'd like to just build the vue structure and then fill them with outside content. So, sounds like the way forward is to utilize axios along with vue-router? Thanks for your help